# Laravel: Undefined variable in blade view

Tags: php, html, laravel, view, laravel-blade

This is `AdminController.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Response;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Caption;
use App\Image;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function admin() {
        $images = Image::paginate();

        return view('admin',[ '$images' => $images]);
    }
}
```

And this is `admin.blade.php`:

```
@extends('template')

@section('title')
    Admin Page
@endsection

@section('header')
@endsection

@section('main')
    @if (Auth::check())
        @foreach ($images as $image)
            <p value='{{$image->id}}'>{{$image->content}}</p>
            <form action="image/{{$image->id}}/delete" method="post">
                <button type="submit">Delete caption</button>
            </form> 
            <form action="image/{{$image->id}}/approve" method="post">
                <button type="submit">Accept image</button>
            </form>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>Login first</p>
    @endif
@endsection

@section('footer')
@endsection
```

Why do I get the following error?

> ErrorException in 408148d5409ae6eebf768dc5721bd0d1d9af48af.php line 9:
>   Undefined variable: images (View: /Users/sahandz/Documents/School/Singapore/CS3226/backend/resources/views/admin.blade.php)

`$images`is clearly defined in my controller.

Comment: try this `return view('admin',compact('images'));`

Comment: is Image::paginate() a scope you wrote? because normally you would do something like this:  `$images = Image::all()->paginate(15);`

Comment: the correction code should be: `return view('admin',[ 'images' => $images]);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have used `$images` as your variable name when passing the data to the view. This results in blade creating a variable called `$$images`.

```
return view('admin',[ 'images' => $images]);
```

will result in the view creating a variable called `$images`

Comment: great, I wasted my 4 hours and finally reached you

Answer (score 2):

Try passing data like this.

```
$images = Image::paginate();
return view("admin")->with('images',$images);
```

Basically,you need not use `$` in the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this

```
public function admin() {
    $images = Image::paginate();

    return view('admin',[ 'images' => $images]);
```

}

Why you use `[ '$images' => $images]`. that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**You may use this method also to pass your data to view**

```
 return view('admin',compact('images'));
```